# What to do about useless questions that see very little traffic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I spend most of my SO time in a couple of tags that get very little traffic. I often see questions that are completely useless, but there's simply not enough traffic to get enough close votes to close a question. Sometimes there are no answers, or sometimes the answer appears in a comment.

Is there anything I should do, or should I accept the fact that these questions will linger forever?

A perfect example is this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13924647/7432

This question is about a problem from years ago that was caused by a one-character typo. While others might have a similar problem, they will likely never stumble on this question since it never included an actual error message (read: it will likely never show up in a search)

Comment: Well posting here is one way to do it. That question is now closed.

Comment: For help (or discussion) on closing new questions -- or old questions with new activity -- drop by the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  chat room

Comment: I don't think a new meta post per questionable question scales.

Comment: @AaronHall: if you're suggesting this question should be closed, by all means vote to close it.

Comment: That was more to Cypher's comment.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If the question is useless (or worse) you can downvote it.  If there really is very little traffic and the question is never improved, upvoted, answered, etc. then the question will be auto-deleted after 30 days if it has a negative score.

You can vote to close it and it has a *chance* of being closed due to the close vote queue, but that's certainly not a sure thing.  While closing such a question would of course be a good thing, if nobody is ever looking at the question or trying to answer it, then closing it is also less helpful than closing questions that are attracting more attention, so trying to organize efforts to close such questions isn't a high priority.

If the question is answered in comments, and is actually an appropriate and on topic question, then post an answer with the solution (citing the work of others as appropriate).

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about the automatic removal. That should work most of the time, though I find many poor questions tend to get a single upvote for some odd reason. <shrug>

Comment: @BryanOakley Downvote them. Deletion is based on the *net* votes.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's the Upvote Bad Posts review queue at work (\*ahem\* I mean the First Posts review queue).

Comment: @BryanOakley [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/266187)

Comment: In OP's case, simply adding the non-version-specific `python` tag probably would have gained enough attention to get it closed.

Comment: @J... Agreed, although there are plenty of questions about topics that wouldn't get enough attention, even if properly tagged.

Comment: *though I find many poor questions tend to get a single upvote for some odd reason.* Probably the people who upvote everything on their screen to hit their quota. Drives me bonkers.

Comment: "If the question is answered in comments, and is actually an appropriate and on topic question, then post an answer with the solution (citing the work of others as appropriate)." Is that cool? I've had more than a few opportunities to do it but wasn't sure if it was frowned upon.

Comment: @miken32 As a general rule I tend to avoid suggesting that people take courses of action that would be inappropriate.  Now, most comments, by themselves, wouldn't make good answers, so you probably need to expand on the point for it to be a *good* answer.